# How do I approach to fixing bugs of Magento 2 code in the custom project?

Tags: magento2, bug

For example, this bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11211
What if I'm building a custom project, based on current Magento 2.2.0 version, and I face with this bug in it's code.

I know that it will be fixed in the upcoming release (2.2.2), however, I need the custom project fixed right now.

How do I approach to fixing this?
What comes to my mind, is to rewrite the involved Model in a custom module.

Is this the best practice to deal with this situation, or there are some smarter ways?